# Upload multiple images, PHP

Tags: php, input

I need to amend an image upload form so I can upload more than one image (6 to be exact). I've tried adding another input and changing the name value as suggested by others, but it still shows up with the same image duplicated from the first input. I know it's probably something simple, but I'm not a PHP developer so I haven't been able to find a solution.

Here's the code for uploading images:

```
if(isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] != '') {
        $tempext = explode('.', $_FILES['image']['name']);
        $tempext = strtolower($tempext[count($tempext) - 1]);
        switch($tempext) {
            case 'jpg':
            case 'jpeg':
                $ext = '.jpg';
                break;
            default:
                $ext = false;
        }

        if($ext != false && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/img/profiles/' . $id . $ext)) {
            $imagesuccess = chmod($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/img/profiles/' . $id . $ext, 0644) ? 'yes' : 'no';
        } else {
            $imagesuccess = 'no';
        }
    }
```

And for the input:

```
<div class="control-container<?php if((isset($_FILES['image']) && !empty($_FILES['image']['name']))) echo ' error'; ?>">
            <label for="image">Large Image</label>
            <div class="multifield">
                <?php 
                if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/img/profiles/' . $id . '.jpg')) {
                    echo '<img src="/img/profiles/' . $id . '.jpg?' . rand() . '" width="310px" />';
                }
                ?>
                <input type="file" name="image" id="image" />
            </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to have multiple input fieldS:

```
<input type="file" name="image1" />
<input type="file" name="image2" />
etc...
```

and access each individual file with:

```
$_FILES['image1'][...]
$_FILES['image2'][...]
etc...
```

or you can use the PHP-specific array notation shortcut:

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" />
<input type="file" name="image[]" />
```

and

```
$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][0];
$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][1];
etc...
```

Note that when using the array notation, PHP makes each individual data-point in the files array its own array. Instead of lumping a file's data together in a single arra, each individual bit is spread about across multiple arrays.

Comment: I've tried both solutions but the form still only sends one image to the database, which is the image uploaded using the last input field.

Comment: What does a `var_dump($_FILES)` show? Go off that for structuring your code.

Comment: Ok, I've messed with it a bit and it looks like it's showing up in the database now. It comes up with a 1 added to the end of the id, even though I've added _02 to the input name and url. It still doesn't seem to want to pull the image down onto the website though.

Comment: You need much better errorhandling. At bare minimum you should have something like `if ($_FILES['image1']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { die("Upload failed with code " . $_FILES['image1']['error']); }`. Never assume an upload succeeded.

Comment: I've figured it out. In the url I was adding . '_02' . after the id, but it was looking for . '1' . I've adjusted everything else and everything seems to be running fine. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

if you have 6 file inputs in your form, $_FILES should come with an array inside it. Check it with `print_r($_FILES)` inside your processing file.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to upload more that file, just change `name` element. For example you can add additional input fields with JavaScript. Every element will have a `name="images[]"` and after submit you can just see what you got by `var_dump( $_FILES )`.

Answer (score 0):

Basic snippet for uploading multiple images:

```
<html>
<?php
define("UPLOAD_DIR", "/path/to/uploads/");

for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]); $i++) {
  if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$i])) {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$i], UPLOAD_DIR . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i]);
  }
}
?>
<body>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="file[]" type="file" /><br />
    <input name="file[]" type="file" /><br />
    <input name="file[]" type="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ryan I think your problem might be within the html part why dont u use a single input it swill do what you whant for example

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="file[]" type="file" multiple="true"><br />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
```