# For loop not giving the expected repetitions

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, for-loop, upload

I have a function in my site that uploads images from the $_FILES array. This function works fine for if you only have a single image, and two or less items in the array, but it can only upload 2 images. For example, my form allows for a maximum of 17 images in the pei_name[] fields but it only uploads the first 2 fields. Here is the function:

```
private function productImageUploader($id, $image, $altText, $uploadDir)
{

    $uploadDir = (!substr($uploadDir, "/")) ? $uploadDir."/" : $uploadDir;
    $image = $_FILES[$image];

    if(is_array($image['name']))
    {
    print_r($_FILES);
        for($i=0; $i<=sizeof($image['name']); ++$i)
        {
            echo $i;
            if($image['error'][$i] != 4)
            {

                $image['name'][$i] = str_replace(" ", "-", $image['name'][$i]);

                $targetPath = $uploadDir.basename($image['name'][$i]);

                if(!move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'][$i], $targetPath))
                {

                    switch($image['error'][$i])
                    {

                        case 1:
                            return "<p class=\"error\">The file for Extra Image {$i} is too large for the server.</p>";
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            return "<p class=\"error\">The file for Extra Image {$i} is too large for the form.</p>";
                            break;

                        case 3:                             
                        case 6:
                        case 7:
                            return "<p class=\"error\">An error occured uploading Extra Image {$i}. Please <a onclick=\"location.reload(true);\">refresh</a> the page.</p>";
                            break;  

                        case 8:
                            return "<p class=\"error\">The file for Extra Image {$i} is not the correct file type. Please convert it to either a jpg, .png or .bmp file.</p>";
                            break;

                    }

                }
                else
                {

                    $thisAlt = (isset($_POST[$altText][$i]) && $_POST[$altText][$i] != "") ? $_POST[$altText][$i] : $_POST['prod_title'];

                    $data = array (
                        'pei_product_id' => $id,
                        'pei_location' => $image['name'][$i],
                        'pei_alt' => $thisAlt
                    );

                    if(!isset($_POST["pei_id"][$i]))
                    {

                        $this->db->insert("product_extra_images", $data);

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        $this->db->where("pei_id", $_POST['pei_id'][$i]);
                        $this->db->update("product_extra_images", $data);

                    }

                    return true;

                }

            }

        }

    }
    else
    {

        if($image['error'] != 4)
        {

            $image['name'] = str_replace(" ", "-", $image['name']);

            $targetPath = $uploadDir.basename($image['name']);

            if(!move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $targetPath))
            {

                switch($image['error'])
                {

                    case 1:
                        return "<p class=\"error\">The file for the main product image is too large for the server.</p>";
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        return "<p class=\"error\">The file for the main product image is too large for the form.</p>";
                        break;

                    case 3:                             
                    case 6:
                    case 7:
                        return "<p class=\"error\">An error occured uploading the main product image. Please <a onclick=\"location.reload(true);\">refresh the page.</p>";
                        break;  

                    case 8:
                        return "<p class=\"error\">The file for the main product image is not the correct file type. Please convert it to either a jpg, .png or .bmp file.</p>";
                        break;

                }

            }
            else
            {

                $data = array ('prod_main_image' => $image['name']);

                $this->db->where("prod_id", $id);
                $this->db->update("products", $data);

                return true;

            }

        }

    }

    if(isset($_POST["pei_id"]) && is_array($_POST["pei_id"]))
    {

        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($_POST["pei_id"]); ++$i)
        {

            $thisAlt = (isset($_POST[$altText][$i]) && $_POST[$altText][$i] != "") ? $_POST[$altText][$i] : $_POST['prod_title'];
            $this->db->where("pei_id", $_POST["pei_id"][$i]);
            $this->db->update("product_extra_images", array("pei_alt"=> $thisAlt));
        }

    }

    return true;

}
```

Here is the contents of the $_FILES array:

```
Array
(
[prod_main_image] => Array
    (
        [name] => 
        [type] => 
        [tmp_name] => 
        [error] => 4
        [size] => 0
    )

[pei_image] => Array
    (
        [name] => Array
            (
                [0] => Untitled.jpg
                [1] => Untitled.jpg
                [2] => Untitled.jpg
                [3] => Untitled.jpg
                [4] => Untitled.jpg
                [5] => Untitled.jpg
                [6] => Untitled.jpg
                [7] => Untitled.jpg
                [8] => Untitled.jpg
                [9] => Untitled.jpg
                [10] => Untitled.jpg
                [11] => Untitled.jpg
                [12] => Untitled.jpg
                [13] => Untitled.jpg
                [14] => Untitled.jpg
                [15] => Untitled.jpg
                [16] => Untitled.jpg
            )

        [type] => Array
            (
                [0] => image/jpeg
                [1] => image/jpeg
                [2] => image/jpeg
                [3] => image/jpeg
                [4] => image/jpeg
                [5] => image/jpeg
                [6] => image/jpeg
                [7] => image/jpeg
                [8] => image/jpeg
                [9] => image/jpeg
                [10] => image/jpeg
                [11] => image/jpeg
                [12] => image/jpeg
                [13] => image/jpeg
                [14] => image/jpeg
                [15] => image/jpeg
                [16] => image/jpeg
            )

        [tmp_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => /tmp/phpGgDKqk
                [1] => /tmp/phpruuIs2
                [2] => /tmp/phpIEbSuK
                [3] => /tmp/phpHDhaxs
                [4] => /tmp/phpigwAza
                [5] => /tmp/phpnEY8BS
                [6] => /tmp/phpEytPEA
                [7] => /tmp/phpRCcEHi
                [8] => /tmp/phpeyUAK0
                [9] => /tmp/php5aQFNI
                [10] => /tmp/php07zSQq
                [11] => /tmp/phppQHdU8
                [12] => /tmp/php8GFGXQ
                [13] => /tmp/phpbaQh1y
                [14] => /tmp/phpqN7Z4g
                [15] => /tmp/phpjPlP8Y
                [16] => /tmp/phpYL3KcH
            )

        [error] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
                [1] => 0
                [2] => 0
                [3] => 0
                [4] => 0
                [5] => 0
                [6] => 0
                [7] => 0
                [8] => 0
                [9] => 0
                [10] => 0
                [11] => 0
                [12] => 0
                [13] => 0
                [14] => 0
                [15] => 0
                [16] => 0
            )

        [size] => Array
            (
                [0] => 172159
                [1] => 172159
                [2] => 172159
                [3] => 172159
                [4] => 172159
                [5] => 172159
                [6] => 172159
                [7] => 172159
                [8] => 172159
                [9] => 172159
                [10] => 172159
                [11] => 172159
                [12] => 172159
                [13] => 172159
                [14] => 172159
                [15] => 172159
                [16] => 172159
            )

    )
```

)

Comment: perhaps the HTML form would be a good thing to share, too?

Comment: I've added the $_FILES array as the form starts off with no fields for the extra images but can add up to 17 via javascript.

Comment: It's a bit contradictive what you're saying. But, based on not looking at your code, it could be that `upload_max_filesize` or `post_max_size` is the culprit.

Comment: @iccthedral Its not these as the file I am uploading is too small.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you've changed about the question and in what manner the previously valid answers no longer apply?

Comment: @PhilFaceplantYoung Who are you going to give the bounty to?

Comment: I added the $_FILES array and the 3rd comment (trying to answer without looking at my code) above wasn't particularly helpful. I haven't found anything that was particularly useful and I answered myself after hours of work (see the accepted answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `return true` was in the wrong place. It needed moving as in this code:

```
private function productImageUploader($id, $image, $altText, $uploadDir)
{

    //$uploadDir = (!substr($uploadDir, "/")) ? $uploadDir."/" : $uploadDir;
    $image = $_FILES[$image];

    if(is_array($image['name']))
    {

        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($image['name']); ++$i)
        {

            if($image['error'][$i] != 4)
            {

                $image['name'][$i] = str_replace(" ", "-", $image['name'][$i]);

                $targetPath = $uploadDir.basename($image['name'][$i]);

                if(!move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'][$i], $targetPath))
                {

                    switch($image['error'][$i])
                    {

                        case 1:
                            return "<p class=\"error\">The file for Extra Image {$i} is too large for the server.</p>";
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            return "<p class=\"error\">The file for Extra Image {$i} is too large for the form.</p>";
                            break;

                        case 3:                             
                        case 6:
                        case 7:
                            return "<p class=\"error\">An error occured uploading Extra Image {$i}. Please <a onclick=\"location.reload(true);\">refresh</a> the page.</p>";
                            break;  

                        case 8:
                            return "<p class=\"error\">The file for Extra Image {$i} is not the correct file type. Please convert it to either a jpg, .png or .bmp file.</p>";
                            break;

                    }

                }
                else
                {

                    $thisAlt = (isset($_POST[$altText][$i]) && $_POST[$altText][$i] != "") ? $_POST[$altText][$i] : $_POST['prod_title'];

                    $data = array (
                        'pei_product_id' => $id,
                        'pei_location' => $image['name'][$i],
                        'pei_alt' => $thisAlt
                    );

                    if(!isset($_POST["pei_id"][$i]))
                    {

                        $this->db->insert("product_extra_images", $data);

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        $this->db->where("pei_id", $_POST['pei_id'][$i]);
                        $this->db->update("product_extra_images", $data);

                    }

                }

            }

        }

        return true;  //This is the moved return

    }
    else
    {

        if($image['error'] != 4)
        {

            $image['name'] = str_replace(" ", "-", $image['name']);

            $targetPath = $uploadDir.basename($image['name']);

            if(!move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $targetPath))
            {

                switch($image['error'])
                {

                    case 1:
                        return "<p class=\"error\">The file for the main product image is too large for the server.</p>";
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        return "<p class=\"error\">The file for the main product image is too large for the form.</p>";
                        break;

                    case 3:                             
                    case 6:
                    case 7:
                        return "<p class=\"error\">An error occured uploading the main product image. Please <a onclick=\"location.reload(true);\">refresh the page.</p>";
                        break;  

                    case 8:
                        return "<p class=\"error\">The file for the main product image is not the correct file type. Please convert it to either a jpg, .png or .bmp file.</p>";
                        break;

                }

            }
            else
            {

                $data = array ('prod_main_image' => $image['name']);

                $this->db->where("prod_id", $id);
                $this->db->update("products", $data);

                return true;

            }

        }

    }

    if(isset($_POST["pei_id"]) && is_array($_POST["pei_id"]))
    {

        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($_POST["pei_id"]); ++$i)
        {

            $thisAlt = (isset($_POST[$altText][$i]) && $_POST[$altText][$i] != "") ? $_POST[$altText][$i] : $_POST['prod_title'];
            $this->db->where("pei_id", $_POST["pei_id"][$i]);
            $this->db->update("product_extra_images", array("pei_alt"=> $thisAlt));
        }

    }

    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here [Upload multiple images, PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772340/upload-multiple-images-php) is something you might look into. I thing this will be helpful for you.